# Is there a way to get code completion on top-level names without assigning a prefix to the import?

Tags: dart

Given something like:

```
import 'dart:math';
```

I can't seem to find a way to get Dart Editor code completion on the top level names unless I do:

```
import 'dart:math' as foo;
```

Is there a special way to do this without specifying a prefix?

Comment: The same thing happens when you don't write `this.` and you instead try to access a class member directly -- the IDE just can't auto-complete it. If you find an issue ticket for this, I'd like to star.

Comment: Thanks for the report! I just made this bug for you: http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=5872  Please star it so you'll get notified.

Comment: Thanks Seth!  Wasn't sure if it was bug-worthy, or if I just overlooked something. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet supported.  See: http://www.dartbug.com/5872